# javascript, looping through a multi-array to list the first element of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

So I feel like I should be able to figure this one out, but for whatever reason, i've having some difficulty with it this morning.

I have an array with multiple arrays inside, and i want to loop through this big array and only list the first element in the smaller arrays.

so my array looks something like this

```
var array = [
             [1, 2],
             [1, 3],
             [3, 4]
            ]
```

So, essentially I want to be able to list, (1, 1, 3). The problem for me is that when i try to approach any for loop, i am able to separate the arrays, but not able to list the first element in each smaller array.

I know this is pretty elementary, and even though i did take a look and did not find much, i do feel like this question has already been asked.

Any help with this would be wonderful.

Much thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** for creating a modified array

```js
var array = [
  [1, 2],
  [1, 3],
  [3, 4]
];

var res = array.map(function(v) {
  return v[0];
});

alert(res)
```

Comment: Oh my, i never thought of going down this route! Thank you so much!

Comment: Amazing...so quick :P

Comment: @kdweber89 : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to list `[1,1,3]`, then this might be enough:

`array.map(function(item) {
  return item[0];
});`

Cheers,
Karol

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
var newArray = [];

array.forEach(function(el) {
   newArray.push(el[0]);
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `for(...)` instead of others for big array. It is fastest. You can see their speed difference in http://jsperf.com/find-first-from-multiple-arrray

[image]

```js
var array = [
    [1, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [3, 4]
], r = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    r.push(array[i][0]);
}
console.log(r);
```